# Terraform Convert map output from module to list to use in other module

Tags: terraform

I managed to use `for_each` to create resources in regions based on a given array. Now I want to use the output URNs to assign the resources to a project in Digital Ocean. The problem is that the way I output the URNs for the resources creates a map while the [project_resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project_resources) resource can only use lists of strings.
My code:

**output.tf**

```
output "droplet_urns" {
  value = tomap({
    for k, drops in digitalocean_droplet.web : k => drops.urn
  })
}
```

How can I convert the map into a list or use the value based on the key? I’m using Terraform v1.1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`keys`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/keys) function to get list with all they keys from the `map`. Also, you can use the [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values) function to get a list with all the values from a `map`.

You would probably need something like:

```
resource "digitalocean_project_resources" "barfoo" {
  project = data.digitalocean_project.foo.id
  resources = values(module.my_module.droplet_urns)
}
```